# I have a listview with items which I want to insert into a SQL Server database

Tags: c#

I want to save content of a listview into a SQL Server database.

I've tried the commented code but get an error

> Must declare scalar variable @Description

Code:

```
private void btnFinish_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

    try
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem item in lvregion.Items)
        {
            SqlConnection conn;
            SqlCommand comm;

            string connectionString = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["conn"];
            conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

            comm = new SqlCommand(
              "INSERT INTO Region (RegionDescription, Fname, Lname) " +
              "VALUES (@RegionDescription, @Fname, @Lname)", conn);
            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("RegionDescription", item.Text.Trim());
            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("fname", item.SubItems[1].Text.Trim());
            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("lname", item.SubItems[2].Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.Add("RegionDescription", SqlDbType.VarChar,40);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("RegionDescription", item.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.Add("Fname", SqlDbType.VarChar,40);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Fname", item.SubItems[1].Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.Add("Lname", SqlDbType.VarChar,40);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Lname", item.SubItems[2].Text.Trim());

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `cmd.Parameters.Add` **and** `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue`, use `cmd.Parameters.Add("RegionDescription", SqlDbType.VarChar,40).Value = item.Text.Trim();`

Comment: You have `cmd` to which you're adding all your parameters - but you also have `comm` which you define a SQL query for and which you execute, You need to use **ONE** `SqlCommand` variable, assign the SQL query to it, add the parameters to it, and then execute it .....

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow,
First up, I wouldn't recommend creating a new connection within your foreach to add items to your table.
Here's what I'd recommend using instead:

```
try
{
    string connectionString = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["conn"];
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd;
        conn.Open();
        string cmdString = @"INSERT INTO Region (RegionDescription, Fname, Lname) 
                             VALUES (@RegionDescription, @Fname, @Lname)";

        foreach (ListViewItem item in lvregion.Items)
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdString, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@RegionDescription", SqlDbType.VarChar, 40).Value = item.Text.Trim();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Fname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 40).Value = item.SubItems[1].Text.Trim();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Lname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 40).Value = item.SubItems[2].Text.Trim(); 
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

(Or at least this should have you on the right path.)

Comment: `using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))` How is that **not** creating a new connection???  Also, `AddWithValue()` ought be avopided in favor of `Add()`

Comment: @MakeStackOverflowGoodAgain I think you may have misread my comment (though it was ambiguously worded), I didn't say "not creating a new connection" but not creating a new connection within a foreach loop, like in the original code.
As for `AddWithValue()`, true enough, seeing as that'll implicitly convert the value passed using an nvarchar. I'll edit my response in a sec.

Comment: Add all your listitems to a datatable and use an adapter to update the datatable